# Duplicate content problem due to plugin

Tags: wordpress, duplicate-content, plugin

Actually I am running website on WordPress where I have installed [Transposh plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/transposh-translation-filter-for-wordpress/) on my site 'example'.

Unfortunately, despite having English as the default language and therefore available at `example.com/xxx`, Google is indexing `example.com/en/xxx` so I'm getting problem with duplicate content now I want to remove this plugin and links from Google so that my content will be refine without getting duplicate content pages.

Do you have any solution to do this safely? I think myself to remove this plugin from website, though it will create 404 errors from Google links but I can add redirect code in *.htaccess* till Google would remove that `example.com/en/xxx` not found links.

If you know any other healthy way to handle this please help me.

Comment: What's stopping you from adding 301 redirect in .htaccess? That's what exactly you should do.

Comment: Have you checked whether the different pages for the same piece of content are differentiated with the primary language HTML tag?

http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-html-lan

Answer (score 2):

A few possible solutions:

1. Use a 301 redirect to redirect all traffic from `/en` to the proper directory as [John](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35130/duplicate-content-problem-due-to-plugin/44122#comment37833_35130) mentioned.
2. Use *robots.txt* to block the `/en` folder. This will keep Google from indexing that folder and hopefully get rid of the duplicate content issues you face.
3. Use Google Webmaster Tools to remove the `/en` directory from Google all together. This would work best in combination with #2.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to remove plugin if it has some use for you. The simplest way is to use 301 redirection or canonical. The Google will automatically replace your desired URL.